# filtered_df and str in Python

Tags: python, string

I am new to Python. I'm trying to filter Dataset. The filter seems to work well  or I think it does:)

```
valid_Cas = ["yut", "thj", "bnm","vfd"]
filtered_df = df[df['Cas ID'].str[-3:].isin(valid_Cas)]
```

but when a filter more than three letters, it does not work,like:

```
valid_Cas = ["yut", "thj", "bnm","vfd","cdret"]
filtered_df = df[df['Cas ID'].str[-3:].isin(valid_Cas)]
```

what does it mean: str[-3:] ?

how can I filter more than 3 letters?

does the code filter "bnm5623" and "5623bnm" or does it leave it?

thank you,

Comment: `str[-3:]` means "the last three items in the list".

Comment: You really should look into indexing syntax. This is not restricted to pandas. `[-3:]` says "from _item 3 from the end of the string_ until the end". If the string is 3 characters, that's the whole string. If it's longer, clearly it's not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what does it mean: str[-3:] ?

`str[-3:0]` is a slicing operation which means "take the last 3 characters of the string". E.g. With a given string like "abcde", `"abcde"[-3:]` would result in `"cde"`. `df['Cas ID'].str[-3:]` performs this slicing operation on each element of the column in the dataframe.

> how can I filter more than 3 letters?

To filter more than 3 characters just adjust the slicing operation to the desired length of string you are looking for. E.g. if you want to filter by strings that end with `'cdret'` you would use `str[-5:]` because `'cdret'` has a length of 5.

> does the code filter "bnm5623" and "5623bnm" or does it leave it?does the code filter "bnm5623" and "5623bnm" or does it leave it?

The code `df['Cas ID'].str[-3:].isin(valid_Cas)` only checks the last three characters of each entry in the 'Cas ID' column against your `valid_Cas` list. So it would recognize `'bnm5623'` as valid if `'562'` is in your list, but it wouldn't recognize `'5623bnm'` as valid because it's looking at the last three characters, which would be `'bnm'`.

To filter more than 3 letters adjust the slicing operator to the longest string in your list. Here is how you would implement this:

```py
valid_Cas = ["yut", "thj", "bnm", "vfd", "cdret"]
max_length = max(len(s) for s in valid_Cas)  # Find the length of the longest string in valid_Cas

# Filter based on the last characters of each string in 'Cas ID', using `max_length`
filtered_df = df[df['Cas ID'].str[-max_length:].isin(valid_Cas)]
```